Decompress SQL Server column field in pyspark (Databricks)
I'm trying to find a way to decompress a column in pyspark from a SQL Server Table exported in parquet.
What i have:
1. SQL Server Table with an xml compressed field
This is the original column type: XML(.)
This is the compressed column type: varbinary(max)
the expression to compress the column is COMPRESS(CAST([unzipped] AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
an extra cast as VARCHAR is needed because as the documentation says XML is not supported as expression for compression
The compression algorithm is gzip - documentation
Tipically to extract the original data this expression works perfectly fine: CAST(DECOMPRESS([zipped]) AS XML)
2. The .parquet extraction of the table made using the "Data Copy" activity of Azure Data Factory
The mapping table - parquet maps the data type of the column like this:



Sql Server Table type
partquet type




varbinary
BINARY



The parquet is saved on the datalake and accessed via Databricks
3. The dataframe column type as read by spark
StructField('column_name', BinaryType(), True)
What i would like to achive:
The goal is to obtain a table where the compressed field is correctly decompressed as xml.
e.g.
Source table



Fields 1 to N
Compressed_field




"Classic" types
BINARY



Target table



Fields 1 to N
Uncompressed_field




"Classic" types
String or XML (if supported)



My Tentative
import gzip
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

# limit on small portion just to test fast, table will be way bigger
parquetFile = spark.read.parquet("path_to_file/file.parquet").limit(10)

# Fast python test to check the algorithm suggest bi the SQL Server documentation is correct (Result is ok)
df = parquetFile.toPandas()
str(gzip.decompress(df['zipped'][0]))

# Now with the whole dataframe
def ungzip(buf):
    result = gzip.decompress(buf)
    return result

ungzip_udf = udf(ungzip, StringType())

parquetFile = parquetFile.withColumn("unzipped", ungzip_udf("zipped"))


My results
The fast python experiments works fine:

But when I use the UDF my the table display seems wrong

what am I missing? Text encoding?
Edit 1
As pointed by siggemannen "gzip.decompress returns bytes, so you need to convert them into string, like: result.decode("Encoding")"
So after modifying the function like this:
def ungzip(buf):
    result = gzip.decompress(buf).decode("UTF-8")
    return result

It works just as intended

gzip.decompress returns bytes, so you need  to convert them into string, like: result.decode("Encoding")

Don't use COMPRESS. SQL Server supports transparent table and index compression  in all supported versions at both the row and page level. There's no reason to use the COMPRESS function. Manual compression prevents querying or indexing that field too.

COMPRESS only made sense in versions before 2016 SP1, when transparent compression became available in all versions and editions, even LocalDB. The oldest version still in mainstream support is 2019, with 2017 in Extended support

What are you trying to do anyway? SQL Server doesn't use Parquet. If you used ADF to export the data to Parquet, it's ADF that should decompress the data before saving it. Otherwise you lose the benefits of columnar storage. If you use transparent compression you can also use SQL Server's XML functions to extract the parts you need into columns that do allow columnar compression. Or convert the XML files into Parquet files

I just need to decompress the data, wich is compressed in that field (one XML per row). Data should not be affected by row and page compression as it have no effect on varbinary datatype.
Parquet file is just a stage to transfer it from the original table to the data lake, then it will be parsed by databricks into a delta table. The table was just like this, and currently XMLs can't be parsed by SQL Server as the table is too big for the current resources

You saying that is not convenient to compress specifically a single field?
For 1mln rows sample a non-compressed table is 2.5GB, with the field compressed is 700MB. Columnstore index is inapplicable to XML

Aside... in a modern Unicode world CAST(SomeXML AS VARCHAR(MAX)) is seldom a safe thing to do. Ref: db<>fiddle
